# If a set A is bounded from above, then the set of upper bouds M has minimum

Tags: proof-verification

I hope the title is clear, because I am Italian and I study calculus exclusively from Italian books.

I had to prove this proposition refusing to look the book (because if I read the proof, I'll forget in two hours and I don't learn).
I tried this but I think it's wrong:

For absurd M has not minimum, then 
$\forall m \in M, \ \exists m'\in M : m'\lt m$

First case, A is open, then $\forall a \in A, \ \exists a'\in A : a'\lt a$

(the two conditions are identical, so M would be an open set)

Can I consider an arbitrary decreasing sequence of $m'$?
Let's call it $m_n$.

So, I can also consider an increasing sequence of $a_n$.
The two sequences approach to the same value $x$;

$x\notin A$ but is greater of all elements of $A$ (it's an upper bound) and $x\notin M$. Absurd.

Second case, $A$ is closed so it has maximum. Maybe the proof can end here?
Boh, I assume again that M has not minimum, so choosing a $m\neq \max A$ I consider $m_n$.

$m_n \to \max A$ that, because of the hypothesis, is not inside $M$. Absurd.

Comment: What if $A$ is neither open nor closed? Also, shouldn't you require $A\ne \emptyset$?

Comment: Ohh, you really right. I wrongly assumed that sets can be only closed or only open. A very bad error. The proof can't be completed with that kind of sets?

Comment: yeah, yeah, $A\neq 0$ but all this go into the trash. I think I should give a look into the book.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to use the least upper bound property.  As $A$ is bounded above, there is some $x$ that is an upper bound to $A$.  Now consider the set of all upper bounds to $A$.  This set is bounded below by any element of $A$, so it has a greatest lower bound $m$.  By the way we picked it $m \in M$, so it is the minimum of $M$.  We don't care if $A$ is open, closed, or neither.